# pickle: How to invoke __setstate__ on contained object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I have class A. It has a constructor that takes arguments. It implements custom pickling with `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`. This works fine.

I have another class, B, which contains an instance of class A as an attribute. Class B *also* implements `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`. How do I get the two of them to cooperate in saving and restoring their state.

It's easy enough to have class B's `__getstate__` to call class A's, but then `pickle` doesn't know anything about it, and when I attempt to restore from B's `__setstate__`, it can't restore the sub-object because it hasn't been instantiated yet.

Example:

```
import pickle

class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y and self.z == other.z

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.x, self.y, self.z

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = state

a = A(1, 2, 3)
a_save = pickle.dumps(a)
assert a == pickle.loads(a_save)
# WORKS FINE TO HERE

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A(1, 2, 3)
        self.b = 4

    def __getstate__(self):
        # Is this correct?
        return self.a.__getstate__(), self.b

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        return self.a.__setstate__(), self.b

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b

b = B()
b_save = pickle.dumps(b)
# Fails in pickle.loads HERE
assert b == pickle.loads(b_save)
```

This produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 41, in <module>
    assert b == pickle.loads(b_save)
  File "p.py", line 33, in __setstate__
    return self.a.__setstate__(), self.b
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'a'
```

How do I reconstruct `a` as an instance of A and restore its original attribute values from the saved state?

(Note this is a toy example created to demonstrate the problem. The real-world code is significantly more complicated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`B` shouldn't invoke `A`'s `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` manually. `B` doesn't even need to know `A` has those methods. It should handle the nested `A` instance exactly as if `A` did not have those methods:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return (self.a, self.b)
def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.a, self.b = state
```

Comment: Well, that was easy. I could have sworn I'd tried that, but I suppose not.